# What is the mistake in the following code using vector here?

Tags: c++, vector

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> decompressRLElist(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<int> pusher;
        for(int i = 0; i<nums.size(); i+=2){
                pusher.push_back(nums.at(i*nums.at(i+1)));
        }
        return pusher;
    }
}
```

I am thinking that the vector is empty at first. So, there should be no problem in using `push_back` in inserting elements into it. But nonetheless, an error is being thrown:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
    what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 8) >= this->size() (which is 4)
```

Comment: what do you think `nums.at(i+1)` refers to when `i = nums.size() - 1`?

Comment: Use the debugger to evaluate `nums.at(i*nums.at(i+1)` when you got the crash.

Comment: @phuclv The size is even. So i think that i can never be nums.size()-1.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I am trying to do that, but getting a different error. If I get anything i shall update. I am doing this on leetcode so building the full program on my own pc.

Comment: @phuclv another code that i tried is: for(int i = 1; i<encoded.size(); i++){
            int z = res.at(i)^encoded.at(i);
            res.push_back(z); but I am getting the exact same error.

Comment: Did you intend to do `nums.at(i)*nums.at(i+1)`?

Comment: @Caleth No. It's exactly what's intended above.

Comment: Why do you think you need to multiply an index by a value? They are different kinds of things that *so happen* to both be represented as `int` in this problem

Answer (score 0):

First, At this line

```
pusher.push_back(nums.at(i*nums.at(i+1)));
```

You do not know what number will be there at `A[i+1]`, here `nums.at(i+1)` which will be multiplied by `i`. Suppose your `i = 5`, and `size = 10`, and `A[i + 1] = 6`, then `pusher.push_back(nums.at(5*6))` will be automatically out range as 5*6 = 30 while the size of `size = 10`.

Second, if you want to access the `i + 1` index in the loop, you have to consider, loop termination condition off by 1.

```
for(int i = 0; i<nums.size() - 1; i+=2)
```

But it will not be working in your case. As your code in the loop is totally flawed. As you did not mention what you want to do so I can not tell you the solution.

Comment: @forageDev Here's the link to the question. "https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-xored-array/". The nums array is already supplied so we know what the next numger is. And where did you get the "pusher.push_back(nums.at(5*6))? If you read it clearly it's pusher.push_back(nums.at(i*nums.at(i+1))). There is no multiplication inside, just addition of 1.

Comment: `i*nums.at(i+1)` as far as I understand this is doing multiplication.

Comment: I guess you are trying to solve this problem. https://leetcode.com/problems/decompress-run-length-encoded-list/

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I posted the wrong link. And yes the link you sent was the one i was referring. I understood what you said. The error was understood and the problem solved. Thank you.